# Output is different for R-value and L-value. Why?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

Can someone explain to me why output for R-value is different from L-value?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<typename Ct>
struct  ct_wrapper {
    Ct&& ct; // R or L ref
    explicit ct_wrapper(Ct&& ct) 
      : ct(std::forward<Ct>(ct)) { std::cout <<  this->ct[1];};
};

int main() {

    // L-val
    vector<int> v{1,2,3};
    ct_wrapper<vector<int>&> lv(v);
    cout << endl << lv.ct[0] << lv.ct[1] << lv.ct[2] << endl;

    // R-val
    ct_wrapper<vector<int>&&> rv(vector<int>{1,2,3});
    cout << endl << rv.ct[0] << rv.ct[1] << rv.ct[2] << endl;
}
```

Output (same for gcc48 and clang32):

```
2
123
2
003
```

**Answer**

It was buried somewhat in my chat with Johannes Schaub, so I've put it here.

When temporary vector initializes  r-value-ref member-variable `rv.ct`, temporary lifetime is not extended because there's a special exception: [class.temporary]p5: "A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor's ctor-initializer (12.6.2) persists until the constructor exits."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your member is just a reference. In the second case the object it references is already dead after the definition of the local `rv` variable has finished. So the later access in the `cout` is undefined behavior.

Comment: +1 (and all other too), but I am still confused. I thought that when temporary bound to r-value ref, its lifetime extended to lifetime of r-value variable.  No? And we still have `rv.ct`.

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky There's a special exception (because it would otherwise be impossible for a compiler to get this right): [class.temporary]p5: "A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor's ctor-initializer (12.6.2) persists until the
constructor exits." (I was going to say the reference isn't bound to a temporary, but to a reference to a temporary, but I don't see that distinction in the standard.)

Comment: @hvd right. Actually the distinction isn't made in clause class.temporary. That clause refers to cases where an expression directly has that attribute. (When text in the Standard says "A prvalue temporary is created ...", then the rvalue directly carries that temporary attribute). Other rules refer to temporary *objects* instead of expressions tagged that way, so one needs to always carefully read the enclosing context to know what is meant (IMHO, the spec is very poor here, it can be made much clearer, see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1299).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it's nice to know I'm not the only one who managed to get confused. :) So it's simpler after all, the initialiser `std::forward<Ct>(ct)` isn't a temporary (in the context of [class.temporary]).

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky: It's really not that confusing: the reference variable is `ct`, and that one only lives for the duration of the constructor.

Comment: @KerrekSB - I think you were talking with hvd :)   Yes, it is not confusing now - after your and Johannes answer. Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Your program has **undefined behaviour** because you are accessing a dangling reference. The temporary vector is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in which it appears, and yet you retain a reference to it.

Answer (score 2):

In the r-value case you bind a temporary to the reference. It will already be gone when you get to the last output statement.